# What to do with legacy after angular v15 update

Tags: angular, angular-material

I did update my app from v14 to v15.

In the update, I can see that Angular changed

```js
// From
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog'

// To
import { MatLegacyDialog as MatDialog } from '@angular/material/legacy-dialog'
```

Does somebody know the reason why?
I searched over on [their website](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) but couldn't find anything useful.

Shall I just set this back to the value it was before?

Comment: @E.Maggini I haven't the paid version '^^

Comment: @E.Maggini But I did had other `legacy` problem and could them find the correct page that helped me out. I've posted an answer to this question

Comment: Medium does not require paid version. Just use incognito mode and you can read the link which has the same solution you posted below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, legacy is the older, deprecated logic that we used to have. *The support will be dropped in the [v17](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v16-is-here-4d7a28ec680d?gi=796916b7e965)*

Angular did change them so that we can migrate them one at the time.

To see the list of changed item, look at the following [github page](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/guides/v15-mdc-migration.md).

So this is safe to leave it as
`import { MatLegacyDialog as MatDialog } from '@angular/material/legacy-dialog'` and refactor the page one at the time.

They also have added a [migration script](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration), so running `ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration` will help you in doing it.

Comment: How long will the legacy components continue to be supported? IS there a deprecation timeline?

Comment: @Ya. They haven't communicate anything yet. I'm updating my comment

Comment: Hovering over MatLegacyDialog it states: @breaking-change — 17.0.0

Comment: FYI. Material legacy will be dropped in v17, it's announced in their v16 blog post, https://blog.angular.io/angular-v16-is-here-4d7a28ec680d "A reminder that we’ll be removing the legacy, non-MDC based components in v17"